# Bizarre inequality involving an algebraic number

Tags: calculus, inequality

In our calculus class today, our teacher explained the [archimedean property](http://planetmath.org/node/33396)
.As food for thought he proposed the following problem :

Given an algebraic number $\
\alpha \,,\,\,a\alpha ^2  + b\alpha  + c = 0\,;\,\,a,b,c \in Z
\
$ prove that $\
\exists \,c > 0\,\,,\,\,\forall \frac{p}{q} \in R
\
$ such that the inequality $\
|\alpha  - \frac{p}{q}| > \frac{c}{{q^2 }}
\
$ holds.

This is the entire text, word for word.This is by far the most bizarre inequality I have ever seen, so I'm wondering if anyone could suggest some useful ideas.

Comment: You should not reuse $c$ between the quadratic and the statement to be proven.  It can cause confusion.  I do not believe they are the same.

Comment: You may be right, I merely copied the exact text our professor wrote on the blackboard. He used $c$ in both the quadratic and the statement to be proven

Comment: Is this really the text word for word?  In addition to the problem Ross Millikan points to, what if $a=0$, so that the "algebraic" number $\alpha$ is actually rational.  In that case $|\alpha-{p\over q}|$ will be *zero* for some $p/q$, hence less than $c/q^2$ for any positive $c$.

Comment: a mere quibble but technically $\alpha$ must be an algebraic irrational

Comment: Yup, this is word for word.

Comment: If we asumme $\alpha$ is irrational algebraic then the claim is true (it's a special case of the well known [Thue-Siegel-Roth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Siegel%E2%80%93Roth_theorem) theorem)

Comment: There is an AMS paper http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/mbk-48-prev.pdf on the subject of rational approximations.  This result is true-algebraic irrational numbers cannot be approximated well by rationals.  It is used in the proof that [Liouville numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) are transcendental

Comment: @Victor, presumably your teacher *said* things as he wrote stuff on the blackboard.  There is a sensible interpretation of what you copied down, and someone will probably post an answer giving a proof of it.  But part of learning math is learning to state things precisely, and that's the first step in this problem.  That's what we're trying to encourage you to do here.

Comment: Trust me I would have mentioned if any other detail was offered, I don't wanna waste anyone's time here. He did NOT give any other details

Comment: @Victor, see in particular Lemma 7.3 and the discussion after it (on pages 213-214) in the AMS paper Ross Millikan linked to.

Comment: @BarryCipra In that AMS paper we were talking about, see Theorem 8.1, why do they take $\
|a - \frac{p}{q}| < 1
\
$ ? Why $<1$ ? I can't get the reasoning behind this and I don't understand why are we allowed to make such an assumption..

Comment: @Victor, if $|\alpha-{p\over q}|\ge1$, then $p/q$ is not really approximating $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a peculiar claim. Surely $\alpha = 1$ is an algebraic number. But taking $p = q = 1$, the inequality doesn't hold for any positive $c$.

Comment: @Barry and I seem to have had the same idea at the same time.

Comment: John, great minds and all that....